# switch case Serializable error in scala

Tags: scala, serialization, switch-statement, deserialization

I want to take a model into a variable let's say (variable name =  Model )
depending on another variable let's call it (variable name  = algoName )
using the switch/match case statement in scala language.

code of what i am doing

---

```
var algoName = "KMeans"
var Model = algoName match {
    case "KMeans" => new KMeans().setK(numberOfClusters).setMaxIterations(numberOfIterations).setSeed(sampleSeed).run(gmmrdd)
    case "BisectingKMeans" => new BisectingKMeans().setK(numberOfClusters).setMaxIterations(numberOfIterations).setSeed(sampleSeed).run(gmmrdd)
}


Model.computeCost(gmmrdd)
```

after running this model is getting stored in Model as

```
Model: Serializable = org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.KMeansModel@760f7ca4
```

now as it is of type "Serializable" so next line is throwing an error

```
<console>:185: error: value computeCost is not a member of Serializable
          Model.computeCost(gmmrdd)
```

but when I do this

```
var Model = new KMeans().setK(numberOfClusters).setMaxIterations(numberOfIterations).setSeed(sampleSeed).run(gmmrdd)
```

output is fine as the Model type is not Serializable

```
 Model: org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.KMeansModel = org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.KMeansModel@1eb211df
```

please help! I know there are many ways this can be done but i want to use match case syntax.

Comment: I think the type of `Model` using pattern matching is Any and it does not contain `computeCost` method. I would suggest to make a trait and declare a method `computeCost` in that and make your `KMeans` and 'BisectingKMeans' extend the trait.

Comment: can you give it as code as i am new to scala.